# WSDL / XSD available but could not find web service URL

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

In the WSDL that is given by Center of medicare and medicaid, there is at the end the name of the Service which is "Core" also the port name "CoreSoapPort" and the binding= "CORE:CoreSoapBinding" however the location is "URL_OF_WEB_SERVICES" 
What am trying to do from my macbook operating on Lion is to parse the wsdl using the command :
wsimport -keep -s src http://www.caqh.org/sites/default/files/core/wsdl/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl
which is the address of the wsdl in order to get the .java and keep them in src that i created on my mac so i can call the web service from my java eclipse.
i was able to get the .java but no web service address?
If any guidance i greatly appreciate it.

---

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the actual webservice running instance, contact your third party so they will provide it.
What Java library do you use?

Comment: Am currently using jars from jdk 8 through maven.

Comment: Well this is not enough to help you. Can you provide part of your code?

Comment: I did not start writing a code since i was not able to parse and get from the wsdl the Service .java and the ServiceSoap.jave

Comment: [WARNING] Ignoring SOAP port "CoreSoapPort": it uses non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.
  line 169 of http://www.caqh.org/sites/default/files/core/wsdl/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl

[WARNING] Service "Core" does not contain any usable ports. try running wsimport with -extension switch.
  line 168 of http://www.caqh.org/sites/default/files/core/wsdl/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl


Generating code...


Compiling code...